Allowed range of L for multielectron in different orbital
From chem.libretexts.org:

Example 11.2.2 : What are the possible $L$ values for the electrons in the [Xe]6s24f15d1?

Solution:
The two extremes for possible $L$ values are $3+2=5$ and $3-2=1$.
Thus, possible values of $L$ for this Xe atom are 5(H), 4(G), 3(F), 2(D), and 1(P)"
I don't understand why 0 is not a possible values of $L$. I know $ml$ of the electron in f orbital is $3$, and the electron in d orbital is $2$, then $L$ would be $5$. But it is possible that $ml$ of both the electron in f orbital and the one in d orbital to be $0$. In such case, won't the $L$ be $0$? Or simply since $L$ cannot be $0$, this microstate is not allowed?

because the series is $|\ell_1+\ell_2| , |\ell_1+\ell_2-1|\cdots |\ell_1-\ell_2|$ and the last value is 1.

So my understanding should be L is a set of number from | l1+ l2 | to | l1- l2 | rather than a number?

@user148520 Not exactly. If you read the question, they are asking for possible values of $L$, which means that it could be any one of the $|l_1 + l_2|$, etc. values. In reality, it will only be one of those for each electron, but that will depend on which electron you refer to.

oic, thank you for the answer!

If you found your answer, feel free to self-answer the question. Self answers are encouraged and it helps future readers.
